# double brackets add "-n" when use eval

Tags: bash, testing, eval, built-in, square-bracket

I'm currently trying to make a dynamic test with [[]] and evaluated code, but there is a **-n** that is added automaticaly at the beginning of the conditions. So my conditions are always true...

Here an example with set -x :

```
myCondition='${queueName} == ${pattern}'
pattern="COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT_PATTERN"
queueName="QM.GCS.SRC.TOTO"
set -x ; [[ $(eval echo $myCondition ) ]] && echo CORRECT; set +x
++ eval echo '${queueName} == ${pattern}'
+++ echo QM.GCS.SRC.TOTO == COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT_PATTERN
+ [[ -n QM.GCS.SRC.TOTO == COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT_PATTERN ]]
+ echo CORRECT
CORRECT
+ set +x
```

Why the -n is added ? Because there is only one parameter ?

How i can make it work as i want ?

Comment: BTW, what's the real use case for this? Generally speaking, `eval` is a code smell (which is [hard to use securely](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)) -- it's generally more appropriate to pass in a function than a string to evaluate, or provide an argument list which can be evaluated as a command, &c.

Comment: i want to make some exceptions management after my elastalert rules (i dont want to modify everytime my rule config. So, i defined a simple text file exception.conf config with format "ID_RULE;CONDITIONS" and then I want to eval the conditions set in the file for each line if the ID_RULE is the correct one. As i have multiple case with differents variables name (ex queueName for a JMS queue, or a componentName for an EAR) I need flexibility in the conditions. The response of Charles Duffy work well `eval "[[ $myCondition ]]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[` implicitly disables string-splitting, such that an expansion isn't split into multiple arguments.

A single-item test implicitly runs `-n`, testing whether that item is the empty string.

Thus, if you want pieces of your condition to be evaluated as separate arguments to `[[`, you should have the `[[` *within* the `eval`, such that the condition is replaced with the text it contains **before** `[[`'s parsing rules are in effect.

```
eval "[[ $myCondition ]]"
```

---

Thus, this would make your code:

```
myCondition='${queueName} == ${pattern}'
pattern="COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT_PATTERN"
queueName="QM.GCS.SRC.TOTO"
set -x ; eval "[[ $myCondition ]]" && echo CORRECT; set +x
```

...which emits on stderr the expected log:

```
+ eval '[[ ${queueName} == ${pattern} ]]'
++ [[ QM.GCS.SRC.TOTO == COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT_PATTERN ]]
+ set +x
```